# How to change state inside the function

Tags: reactjs

I'm doing react component. I have a common ajax call inside the funtion:

```
getPost = (postName, storage) => {
    this.setState({fetchInProgress: true})
    $.ajax({
       url: "/api/getitems",
       type: "GET",  
       dataType: 'json',  
       ContentType: 'application/json',
       data: {modelName: postName},
       success: (data) => {
         this.setState({
               storage: data,
               fetchInProgress: false
             })

       },  
       error: (jqXHR) => {
         this.setState({fetchInProgress: false})
         console.log('ERRORR')
       } 
    })
  }
```

I call it like this:

```
this.getPost('StandartPost', this.state.standartPosts)
```

but it doens't work. I have many different types of posts. For now I did this with switch:

```
  success: (data) => {
         switch(postName){ 
           case: 'StandartPost'
           this.setState({
               standartPosts: data,
               fetchInProgress: false
             })
           ...and so on
         }
       }
```

Here I'm not using the second parameter of my function. But also there is too much code. Is there a way to do it like this:

```
success: (data) => {
             this.setState({
                   storage: data,
                   fetchInProgress: false
                 })

           }

this.getPost('StandartPost', this.state.standartPosts)
```

**UPD**: I just tried to use this.state.something as a key inside this.setState method:

```
                 this.setState({
                   this.state.data: data,
                   fetchInProgress: false
                 })
```

well, it does nothing. this.state.data is still an empty array.

**UPD2**: I 've done the following in my ajax call:

```
success: (data) => {
         this.state[storage] = data
         this.setState({
           fetchInProgress: false
         })
```

and call the function getPost(postName, storage) like this:

```
this.getPost('StandartPost', 'standartPosts')
```

And it works fine. I dind't find a way to  set the data inside setState method. But at least there is less code.

Comment: What error do you get if any?

Comment: I do not have any error nor in my server nor in by react-component. But  my component doesn't render any data.

Comment: Create a componentDidUpdate(prevState){} and console.log both prevState.standartPosts and this.state.standartPosts to check if the problem is your setState(){} not changing the state

Comment: It shows me an empty array. I guess I'm not allowed to use this.state.something as key value inside this.setState method. It is not an error but it does nothing.

Comment: Yes you can, i use it to change booleans of toggles all the time, that's not the problem

Comment: Like this: this.setState({ this.state.data: data }) ? As a key?

Comment: this.setState({data: this.state.data}), but in this example it wouldn't change anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Do not modify state directly](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly). You should only assign state directly in your constructor.

Using [ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/using-a-variable-for-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-literal/2274327#2274327), you can set use a variable as an object key by wrapping the variable in square brackets as follows:

```
this.setState({
  [storage]: data,
  fetchInProgress: false
});
```

If not, you could have created a new object, say `newState`, and passed that into `setState`:

```
success: (data) => {
  let newState = {
    fetchInProgress: false
  };  
  newState[storage] = data;
  this.setState(newState);
}
```